# Splitting String to list of Integers with comma and "-"

Tags: java, string, parsing

Is there a simple way to parse the following String to List of Integers:

```
String s = "1,2,5-9,11,12"

// expected values list: [1,2,5,6,7,8,9,11,12]
List<Integer> values = magicallyGetListFromString(s);
```

I was wondering if there is a simple way to do it, rather than writing it by myself.

Comment: `StringTokenizer` is too complex?

Comment: Yes, write some Java code to parse it. What is your *specific* question.

Comment: see there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: I know how to do it by myself (very similar to @SteveL answer). I was looking for an existing code to do it...

Comment: @mxb: `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class, and it is discouraged to use it in new code.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder ,well you should had mentioned what exactly you are looking for , "simple" doesn't mean the same to everyone.

Comment: @SteveL you are right! in my head it sounded very clear to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Integer> out=new ArrayList<Integer>();
String numbers[]=s.split(",");
for(String part:numbers){
    if(part.contains("-"){
        int a=Integer.parseInt(part.split("-")[0]);
        int b=Integer.parseInt(part.split("-")[1]);
        while(a<=b){
             out.add(a++);
        }
    }else{
        out.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "1,2,5-9,11,12,19-21";
    String[] val = str.split(",");
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (String s : val) {

        if (s.contains("-")) {
            String[] strVal = s.split("-");
            int startVal = Integer.parseInt(strVal[0]);
            int endVal = Integer.parseInt(strVal[1]);
            for (int i = startVal; i <= endVal; i++) {
                l.add(i);
            }
        } else {
            l.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
        }
    }
    for (int j : l) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

O/P :
1
2
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
19
20
21

Comment: My guess is that it would keep the ,s and -s but not the actual numbers.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public class StringMagic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "1,2,5-9,11,12";

        // expected values list: [1,2,5,6,7,8,9,11,12]
        List<Integer> values = magicallyGetListFromString(s);
        for (Integer integer : values)
        {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer> magicallyGetListFromString(String s)
    {
        List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        String[] numbers = s.split(",");
        for (String string : numbers)
        {
            if (!string.contains("-"))
            {
                numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(string));
            }
            else
            {
                String[] limits = string.split("-");
                int bottomLimit = Integer.parseInt(limits[0]);
                int upperLimit = Integer.parseInt(limits[1]);
                for(int i = bottomLimit; i <= upperLimit; i++)
                {
                    numberList.add(i);
                }
            }
        }
        return numberList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magic you are looking at

```
public static List<Integer> magicallyGetListFromString(String s){
   String[] str=s.split(",");
   List<Integer> result=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   for(String i:str){
       if(i.contains("-")){
           String[] ss=i.split("-");
           int lower= Integer.parseInt(ss[0]);
           int upper= Integer.parseInt(ss[1]);
           for(int j=lower;j<=upper;j++){
               result.add(j);
           }
       }else {
           result.add(Integer.parseInt(i));
       }
   }
    return result;
}
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12]
```